# combine multiple update statements into one update

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a sql server 2012 database that has a table with a column called "gameRoomText" with data that looks something like this:

```
<p>
<img id="4e" style="margin: 5px" 
title="GameFiles/1854/4e.jpg (media placeholder image)" 
src="../images/nothing_null.png" 
alt="GameFiles/1854/4e.jpg (media placeholder image)" 
width="320" height="380" /></p>
```

I need to get rid of all the rows that contain text like this:

> src="../images/nothing_null.png"

So I start by getting rid of the string " (media placeholder image)" :

```
update gameList
set gameText = replace(gameText, ' (media placeholder image)', '')
where gameID = '1854'
and tileID = '0FE'
and gameText LIKE '%src="../images/nothing_null.png"%'
```

Then I remove the exiting src tag:

```
update gameList
set gameText = replace(gameText, 'src="../images/nothing_null.png" ', '')
where gameID = '1854'
and tileID = '0FE'
```

Now I change the "alt" tag to a "src" tag:

```
update gameList
set gameText = replace(gameText, 'alt=', 'src=')
where gameID = '1854'
and tileID = '0FE'
```

And finally, I add a "../" into the new "src" tag path like so:

```
update gameList
set gameText = replace(gameText, 'src="', 'src="../')
where gameID = '1854'
and tileID = '0FE'
```

These work, however I was wondering if there's a way to combine these 4 update statements into one, so that I only need to run one update statement for every game tile "tileID" and game "gameID" that might have these issues.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can chain the replace statements but it gets messy real quick.  For instance:

```
update gameList
set gameText = replace(replace(replace(replace(gameText, ' (media placeholder image)', ''), 'src="../images/nothing_null.png" ',''), 'alt=', 'src='), 'src="', 'src="../')
where gameID = '1854'
and tileID = '0FE'
and gameText LIKE '%src="../images/nothing_null.png"%'
```